# PSQL outer join keep joined columns unique

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, outer-join, psql

Say I have two tables that look like the following:

Student

```
age|name|gender
---+----+------
 3 |jon | M
 4 |mike| M
 2 |Sue | F
```

Teacher:

```
experience|name|college
----------+----+-------
10 years  |Sue | UVA
23 years  |Tom | Yale
9 years   |Bob | Harvard
```

When performing an outer join, how would I combine this table while being able to identify the difference between Sue Teacher and Sue Student?

Comment: By adding a unique id.

Comment: Could you post an example in an answer format?

Comment: And also, show us your current select, and describe whats wrong with it!

Comment: If you are doing an outer join, there should be column(s) common to both tables. I don't see any. As @jarth says, give us more details and perhaps we can help.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean a `UNION` instead of an outer join?

```
SELECT 'student' as type, name
  FROM student
 UNION SELECT 'teacher' as type, name
  FROM teacher
```